# How to print and assign values of a solution from CHOLMOD to a std::vector in C++?

Tags: c++, suitesparse

I am trying to solve a simple working example, a linear system $Ax=b$, where $A$ is sparse SPD and $b$ is dense, using [CHOLMOD](https://github.com/DrTimothyAldenDavis/SuiteSparse/tree/master/CHOLMOD).

```
int main()
{

    std::vector<double> A = {4.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                             0.0, 3.0, 1.0,
                             1.0, 1.0, 2.0};

    std::vector<double> B = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    size_t n = sqrt(A.size());    
    b = cholmod_allocate_dense(n, 1, n, CHOLMOD_REAL, &c);
    b->x = &*B.begin();
    cholmod_triplet *T;

    // Fill T

    a = cholmod_triplet_to_sparse(T, Tx.size(), &c);    
    L = cholmod_analyze(a, &c);
    cholmod_factorize(a, L, &c);
    x = cholmod_solve(CHOLMOD_A, L, b, &c);

    return 0;
}
```

Does someone know how to print the values of `x = cholmod_solve(CHOLMOD_A, L, b, &c)` and how to assign his values to a `std::vector`? As I do not know how to print and assign the values of the solution, I even know whether my code is working properly.

I have tried to print the values using std::cout and also printf.

Comment: seems like you are looking for [cholmod_print_dense](https://github.com/DrTimothyAldenDavis/SuiteSparse/blob/master/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_check.h) function to print `x`.

Comment: @seleciii44, this function just show `CHOLMOD dense:   x:  3-by-1,   OK`, not the elements of x->x.